# Как передать в функцию координаты поиска в ассоциативном массиве?

Tags: javascript

Как передать в функцию координаты поиска в ассоциативном массиве для изменения значения?

```
var arr={
  'name_1':{'name_2':{'name_3':[0,1]}},
  'name_4':{'name_5':[0,1]},
  'name_6':[0,1]
}
function fun(val,search){
  val[search] = 0 // 'Значение которое может быть только внутри функций';
  console.log(val)
}

fun(arr,['name_1','name_2'])
fun(arr,['name_4','name_5'])
fun(arr,['name_6'])
```

Мне нужно получить копию arr изменить одно значение которое может находиться на разных слоях массива
а после вернуть массив с измененным значением.

Как я могу это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь парой хелпер функций из `lodash`. Можете заимпортить всю либу или из исходников стянуть указанные ниже функции `cloneDeep` и `set`.

```
function cloneAndAssign(source, path) {
    const target = _.cloneDeep(source);
    _.set(target, path, 0 /* ваше значение */);
    return target;
}
```